# Are my Club Nintendo coins going to expire?

Tags: club-nintendo

I've read somewhere that all coins are going to expire after June 30 (2 club nintendo years) but when I login, I read this:

```
Coin Expiration: Please note that unredeemed Coins expire after 2 Club Nintendo years (July 1 - June 30).

You have 0 expiring Coins on June 30, 2012
```

So are my coins going to expire after the 30th or not? This is the only mention I've seen that says they will not expire, is it a glitch? If they don't expire on the 30th, when will they?

Comment: Given the number of coins you have now, is this actually greater than the amount of coins you've registered since July 1, 2010? If it isn't - if you currently have the same or fewer coins than you've gained since that date - there's nothing incorrect about this message; *you* don't have any coins which will expire, but for simplicity, they show the message to everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now, none of your coins are going to expire.

Basically, how it works is you have 2 Club Nintendo years (July 1 to the following June 30) to use coins you have gotten from registering games and doing surveys, etc.

What this means is, if you were to register a game today, you would have 2 CN years from TODAY to use them.

If you registered a game a year ago, you have one more CN year to use them.

It is basically a floating window of time based upon whenever you registered the game.